# Adding whitespace in a DAX expression for display in PBI Card

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm using Power BI to create a report.I'm creating a card where I have to show product sales/target sales.
The following measure is being displayed on the card.

```
Measure 2 = ROUND(sum('Sales by Category'[ProductSales]),0) & "  /  " & Round(sum('Sales by Category'[TargetSales]),0)
```

I need some gap at both sides of the slash i.e `25000   /   30000` .
But Even if I give multiple number of spaces before and after the `/` in the DAX expression,the resultant card looks like this.
 `25000 / 30000`

only one whitespace is being displayed on both sides of the `/`.
Is there any way to add a whitespace, like a `'\t'` or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting findings. I believe it's some built-in logic behind the visualizations which causes such inconsistent behavior.

It happens with `Card` and `Multi-row card` but not `Table` and `Matrix`:

[image: inconsistent behavior]

With that said, to workaround with such behavior, you can use some other whitespace character, for example the whitespace in fullwidth form 　:

```
Measure = 123 & "　　　　　/         " & 456
```

Results: (The left part is fullwidth whitespace)

[image: results]

Comment: I took your suggestion and tried it in table and matrix visuals,but the same thing is happening.
Are you using the Power BI desktop or the service?

Comment: 1. The behavior you mentioned only happened to me for cards but not table and matrix. Table and matrix respect the normal spaces (See image above) 2. I'm using Power BI Desktop.

Comment: I'm using the desktop version too. anyway I'll proceed by using the fullwidth whitespace. Thank You.

Answer (score 9):

Create new measure like

**WhiteSpace = UNICHAR(127)**

And use it any where you need this like

**Currentday = FORMAT(NOW(),"mm/dd/yy" & REPT(*WhiteSpace*,4) & "(DDD)")**

Result :
01/18/22    (WED)

Comment: Power BI ignores whitespaces if wordwrap option is enabled but some time we need wordwrap enabled and also need white spaces.

Answer (score 2):

In the latest Power BI desktop tool, we can turn off the word-wrap feature. Then it will show all the `whitespaces`.

[image: word-wrap feature]

[image: Output]